# Pillow data handling

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, python-imaging-library

I want to use pillow for saving Image and loading it.

I know I can do Image.save(imagename.xxx).

But I want to save as the contents of images.

and I want to reuse it .

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

filename = 'any_image.png'
import pickle
im = Image.open(filename)
data = list(im.getdata())
f = open("test_file.dat","wb")
dumps = pickle.dump(data,f)

f = open("test_file.dat","rb")
tumps = pickle.load(f)
print(np.asarray(tumps))
#here
re_im = Image.Image.putdata(tumps)
re_im.show()
```

I want to show re_im Image Object, it is the same contents I saved before.
I could save & load of the same contents by pickle.

But I don't know where I send the contents.
I want to show the same as original image by `re_im.show()`

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make it.

first, to omit 'data = list(im.getdata())'
second, to insert 'np.array(im)'

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
filename = 'any_data.png'
import pickle
im = Image.open(filename)
data = np.array(im)
f = open("test_file.dat","wb")
print(type(data))
dumps = pickle.dump(data,f)
f = open("test_file.dat","rb")
tumps = pickle.load(f)
array = Image.fromarray(tumps)
array.show()
```